# Rails: difference between :source => ?? and :class_name => ?? in models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I'm having trouble conceptualizing when to use `:source` and when to use `:class` for my more complex models.

Here I have an example of users with friends.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :friendships, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :friends, :through => :friendships, :conditions => "status = 'accepted'"
  has_many :requested_friends, :through => :friendships, :source => :friend, :conditions => "status = 'requested'", :order => :created_at
  has_many :pending_friends, :through => :friendships, :source => :friend, :conditions => "status = 'pending'", :order => :created_at
end


class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :friend_id, :user_id, :status

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => 'friend_id'
end
```

Can someone explain why for Friendship it's `:class_name` instead of `:source`? Is this because that's just the pairing (has_many + :source , belongs_to + :class_name)?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

They are conceptually the same, just need to be different for different uses.

`:source` is used (optionally) to define the associated model name when you're using `has_many  through`; `:class_name` is used (optionally) in a simple `has many` relationship.  Both are needed only if Rails cannot figure out the class name on its own.  See the [documentation for has_many in the API here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many).

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. I use `:class_name` on most of my `has_many :through` associations and it works fine. Is one just an alias of the other? And when you say "Both are needed only if Rails cannot figure out..", do you mean both `:class_name` and `:source` should be provided simultaneously? Is that ever necessary? (the reason I ask is because I just found an assoc in my code that had both, which had me Googling to discover the distinction once and for all). Thanks for your answer thus far, I think I'm very close to understanding the difference! (if there even is one...)

Comment: The only time I think you would need to do source and classname is if you are doing a different has many through name and have a subclassed model. So for instance imagine Fantasy Football. You have a User, User::Player, and User::Commissioner that belong to leagues through user_leagues. If you write has many players through player leagues and want to refer to User::Player then you will need the class_name and source. At least I think so ;).

Answer (score 1):

Here are examples of usage of :source and :class_name.

`has_many :subscribers, through: :subscriptions, source: :user`

`has_many :people, class_name: "Person"`

As you can see when you use a through table you end up using `source` else you use `class_name`.

Look at the option examples in this link:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many