# Multiple many-to-many association between two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, associations

I've created a many to many relation ship like the following structure.

```
Class User
 has_many :companies, :through => company_admins
 has_many :company_admins
end

Class Company
 has_many :company_admins
 has_many :users,  :through => company_admins
end

Class CompanyAdmin
 belongs_to :company
 belongs_to :user
end
```

Here, `User` can be assigned as admin on many `Company`.

Now I've to create another many-to-many relationship with `User` and `Company`, where `User` can follow many `company`. How can I do that?

I've added

```
Class User
 has_many :companies, :through => company_admins
 has_many :companies, :through => followers
 has_many :company_admins
 has_many :followers
end

Class Company
 has_many :company_admins
 has_many :followers
 has_many :users,  :through => company_admins
 has_many :users,  :through => followers
end

Class Follower
 belongs_to :company
 belongs_to :user
end
```

Now, If I search for users  which are admin to any company using `@company.users` it searches in the `Follower` table. 
Can anyone help me with the association?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your association set up should be something like this

```
#user.rb
Class User
 has_many :company_admins
 has_many :companies, :through => company_admins
 has_many :followers
 has_many :followed_companies, :through => followers, :source => :company
end

#company.rb
Class Company
 has_many :company_admins
 has_many :users, :through => company_admins
 has_many :followers
 has_many :followed_users, :through => followers, :source => :user    
end

#follower.rb
Class Follower
 belongs_to :company
 belongs_to :user
end
```

Now if you give `@company.users`, it will search in `company_admins` table and if you give `@company.followed_users`, it will search in `followers` table.

***Note:*** Didn't tested.

Comment: One more thing, you've used `:class_name`. I've seen someone using `:source`. Could you tell me the difference?

Comment: @Emu Actually it should be `source`. This post explains in detail http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13611265/rails-difference-between-source-and-class-name-in-models