# Difference between class_name and source

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am really confused about the difference between `class_name` and `source` options of `has_many`.

For `class_name`, it is said on the API doc that:

> Specify the class name of the association. Use it only if that name can’t be inferred from the association name. So has_many :products will by default be linked to the Product class, but if the real class name is SpecialProduct, you’ll have to specify it with this option.

And for `source`:

> Specifies the source association name used by has_many :through queries. Only use it if the name cannot be inferred from the association. has_many :subscribers, through: :subscriptions will look for either :subscribers or :subscriber on Subscription, unless a :source is given.

It seems that these two options have the same function, that is, to specify the class name of the association, except that `source` is only used for `has_many :through`, and `class_name` can be set in every `has_many` association.

If so, why it is necessary for `has_many` to have these two options with the very similar functions? Why just use `class_name` only to specify all the association name?

I searched in many places but could not find the answer. I also read [Rails: difference between :source => ?? and :class_name => ?? in models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13611265/rails-difference-between-source-and-class-name-in-models) ,but it still does not explain why it is necessary for the existences of both `class_name` and `source`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The key point is **class_name** specify the ***class name*** of the association where **source** specifies the source ***association name***.

Example:

```
lass User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :listing_managers
  has_many :managed_listings, through: :listing_managers, source: :listing
end

class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :listing_managers
  has_many :managers, through: :listing_managers, source: :user
end

class ListingManager < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :listing
  belongs_to :user
end
```

On the above code example `user` is `class_name`. When we are declaring `has_many :managers, through: :listing_managers` then rails is expecting there is either `manager or managers` association with in `ListingManager` . Since we want to use `user` association for creating `managers` we have to tell it to rails that make `managers` association using ListingManager's `user` association.

Here is another example that use `class_name` option

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :listing_managers
  has_many :listings, through: :listing_managers
end

class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :listing_managers
  has_many :managers, through: :listing_managers
end

class ListingManager < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :listing
  belongs_to :manager, class_name:"User"
end
```

On the above code we are declaring `belongs_to :manager` association on `ListingManager` but there is no model named `manager` that's why we have to set `class_name` option. Now, since we have `manager` association on 
`ListingManager` we don't need to set `source` option on `Listing` that we  had to do on first example.

Hope above will help someone.