# Two similar Many-to-Many Relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, many-to-many, associations, has-many-through

I have two similar M:M relationships that I work with individually however I don't know how to them working without conflicting.

Relationships are Players & Teams

> 1) Many players "play for" many teams
>
> 2) Many players "are members of" many teams

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :plays
  has_many :members
  has_many :teams, through: :plays
  has_many :teams, through: :members
end

class Teams < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :plays
  has_many :members
  has_many :players, through: :plays
  has_many :players, through: :members
end

class Play < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :players
  belongs_to :teams
end

class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :players
  belongs_to :teams
end
```

I need to be able to find:

```
Player.find(21).teams #who he plays for
Player.find(21).teams #who he is a member of
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give a different name to each `has_many` association, and use the `source` parameter to specify the actual association name.

Like this:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :plays
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :played_with_teams, through: :plays, source: :team
  has_many :member_of_teams, through: :memberships, source: :team
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :plays
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :played_players, through: :plays, source: :player
  has_many :member_players, through: :members, source: :player
end

class Play < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player
  belongs_to :team
end

class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player
  belongs_to :team
end
```

That can be used like this:

```
Player.find(21).played_with_teams #who he plays for
Player.find(21).member_of_teams #who he is a member of
```

Hint: I updated the answer.

Comment: What's the difference between class_name: 'Team' and source: 'Team' ?

Comment: checkout this for an explanation on the difference: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13611265/368167